# ConstrainLayout not able to align two views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I want to align **Sachin** Textview with **Tendulkar** Textview.

Screenshot:
[image]

Design time I'm getting proper alignment. But it fails in app.

XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFirstName"
        style="@style/MediumBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="First Name: "
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLastName"
        style="@style/MediumBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last Name: "
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tvFirstName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFirstName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        style="@style/SmallGray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Sachin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvFirstName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tvFirstName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@style/SmallGray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tendulkar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tvLastName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47" />
```

> is there any android studio-constraintlayout specific feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints on "Tendulkar" are causing the `TextView` to be centered. You want to align the left side of that `TextView` with the left side of "Sachin" as follows:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    style="@style/SmallGray"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tendulkar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tvLastName"/>
```

I also removed the bias.